# Can I run a third-party Eclipse plugin as a standalone RAP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I am using a freeware third-party Eclipse plugin ([Toad Extensions for Eclipse](http://toadextensions.com/index.jspa?product=eclipse), which I really love), and I'm interested if I can run that plugin in a [Rich Ajax Platform (RAP)](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/) container with little effort. If that was possible, I could run a simple intranet server for shared database access, using this splendid tool.

Of course, I will double-check licenses again, before actually doing it. But I'm wondering about the technical feasibility...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common procedure is to import the source code of this extension into an Eclipse workspace, switch the target platform to a recent RAP target, and change the dependencies from org.eclipse.ui to org.eclipse.rap.ui. Include any non-Eclipse-UI dependencies into the target.

After this, look for compile errors in the Problems view. These compile errors give you an idea of those API functions that your plugin needs but are not available in RAP.

For this mismatch, you have two options: either you modify the code so that it does not need this unsupported API anymore, or you try to provide a replacement for the missing features in RAP. The [RAP forum/newsgroup](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.technology.rap) will surely assist you to sort out which things are doable and which rather not.

Good luck!

Comment: So it's not really feasible with a couple of clicks. Besides, I think the library is closed-source so, probably it's not possible...